# PHP Register system - wrong passwort error css

Tags: php, html, css, layout

when someone types his username or password wrong, I wanted to highlight the login box with red color, but it gave me a fail aspect.

How I wanted: 
[image]

How I made:

[image]

HTML

```
    <div class="login">
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input type="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/uVoJ8Kl.pngg" />
</form>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php

 require('config.php');
 session_start();
 // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
 if (isset($_POST['password'])){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $username = stripslashes($username);
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
 $password = stripslashes($password);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
 //Checking is user existing in the database or not
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".sha1($password)."'";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($rows==1){
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 header("Location: profile.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
 }else{
 echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username sau parola gresita. Click</h3><br/>Click  <a href='login.php'>aici</a> pentru a reveni la pagina de login</div>";
 }
 }else{
 }
?>
```

Can you give me a hint how to fix it?

Comment: First, the `header` function is not redirecting to index.php as the comment says. And why there is an empty else? how are you expecting the inputs to be highlighted when you are `echo`ing a div element?

Comment: I didn't show the full code, I just show only that part.  Let me edit with full code.

Comment: Good thing you showed the code, stop using mysql_* functions they are deprecated, use mysqli instead

Comment: Thank you @MehdiBounya  but I'm trying to learn the language of coding,  when I will try to go further into more complex things, i will use mysqli, until then I just want to learn.  And I can't figure it out why I can't make my box highlighted at wrong password

Comment: You can't highlight the input because simply your code doesn't have such feature, you are echoing a div element, how is that supposed to highlight the inputs? plus, your strategy of **I just want to learn** is bad, start learning good practices from now so you can get used to them.